# A TextEditingController was used after being disposed error

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBZgs.png)> a texteditingcontroller was used after being dispose.once you have called dispose() on an texteditingcontroller,it can no longer be used htttps://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

i expect show map search bar but its show a texteditingcontroller was used after being dispose.once you have called dispose() on an texteditingcontroller,it can no longer be used htttps://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

Comment: The error message indicates that your text controller is being used after it has been disposed. To address this, please provide your code.

Comment: Please add your code for easier references